# Goto specific home screen

Tags: android, homescreen

I would like to design a specific background application for a booth that would need to go to a specific home screen depending of on a selected value...

Does anyone knows a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own custom Launcher. The Launcher is just another app, and home screens are nothing more than its UI display, there’s nothing built into Android itself that controls that.